# business math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If Profit = Revenue - Costs (or P = R - C) and we want to calculate the change of Cost (which is ∆c), can you do so when you know the change of P and R (being ∆p and ∆r respectively)?

So if ∆p x P = ∆r x R - ∆c x C, and ∆p and ∆r are known, can we derive a formula for ∆c in terms of ∆p and ∆r that would be valid for any values of P, R and C (which can be assumed to be known for this example)? F.e. if revenue is up by 25% (∆r = 1.25) and profits are down 20% (∆p = 0.8), how much did costs change by?

I've been trying to solve it on my own for an hour but I'm stuck. Help is much appreciated, Gian

Comment: Are you sure this is Linear Algebra?

Comment: no I actually am not sure where to categorize this, so I took a basic tag. What category or tag would you put this under?

Comment: One reason you probably didn't get as quick replies was that you tagged this as "linear algebra," which, by the way, has very little to do with basic algebra and linear equations like $y=mx + b$. Next time, try "algebra-precalculus." Linear Algebra has to do with "vector spaces of all dimensions and linear transformations between them, including systems of linear equations, bases, dimensions, subspaces, matrices, determinants, traces, eigenvalues and eigenvectors, diagonalization, Jordan forms, etc." I don't even understand half of those words. :)

Comment: thanks ill pay better attention next time.

Comment: If you understand everything, then accept the solution so it doesn't show up as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given $\Delta p*P = \Delta r*R - \Delta c*C$, we can definitely isolate a variable.

Then, $\Delta c*C = \Delta r*R - \Delta p*P$.

Then, $\Delta c = \frac{\Delta r*R - \Delta p*P}{C}$.

Trying some numbers out, let's assume your profit is $\$100$, revenue is $\$150$, and costs are $\$50$.

Then let's use your example that revenue is up $25\%$ and profits are down $20\%$. Our new profit is $\$80$, and our revenue is now $\$187.5$.

Therefore, our cost now is $\$107.5$. (Simple subtraction)
$\$107.5 = \Delta c*C = \Delta c*50 \to \Delta c = 2.15$ or $215\%$.

Using our formula, $\Delta c = \frac{\Delta r*R - \Delta p*P}{C}$, we get:

$\Delta c = \frac{1.25*150 - 0.8*100}{50}$, which results in the same value.

Notice how increasing by $25\%$ is written as $1.25$, and decreasing by $20\%$ is written as $0.8$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was insightful. I have to excuse myself for asking such a basic question, I'm brushing up on my math. Thanks again!

Comment: I was actually trying to figure if there was a formula for Δc with only Δr and Δp, so if we could retrieve Δc without knowing P, R and C, I'm guessing no, but I'm not certain why.